# What's the grammar of "with such transitions governed"?

Tags: grammar, past-participles, clauses

It's not uncommon to use *with* to introduce a clause like this:

> A particle's energy state jumps about randomly, with such transitions governed by the temperature of the system.

What's the grammar rule validating this expression and the use of *with* with the past participle?

If there is grammatical terminology to describe this, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

*With* is a preposition. The prepositional object is *such transitions governed by the temperature of the system.* You can use *with* to form an adverbial phrase of condition or circumstance, as in this case. A simple example:

> The balloon popped with a loud bang.

Within the prepositional object in your example, you could say the participle or participial phrase is **predicative**, which means that it "actively" assigns a property to its head (the noun) the way a subject or object complement does; this is opposed to *attributive* adjectives, which merely "passively" mention a property of a noun. The "fact" that it is predicative can be seen by the fact that it is clearly linked to a specific head-noun (*such transitions*) but appears after it rather than before it; attributive modifiers normally appear before their heads, while predicative modifiers normally appear after them.

This predicative use sounds very slightly informal to me when you use it after *with*.

The following is the same kind of adverbial constituent with internal predication, but in a simpler sentence:

> She left the area, with her daughter in the back seat.

Here the adverbial phrase/constituent *with her daughter in the back seat* has an internal predication: the adverbial phrase *in the back seat* assigns a property (location) to its head, *her daughter*. So the adverbial phrase *in the back seat* serves the same function as the participle *governed* does in your example.

Comment: Thanks @Cerberus ! It's very clear and helpful. Does the comma before _with_ make any difference?

Comment: @ColinZ: Great! The comma does not change anything if you leave it out, but it is advisable to use a comma here, because it is a rather long adverbial constituent that is not closely connected with the core of the main clause.